# Is "reign" a countable or uncountable noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, uncountable-nouns

I'm editing an advanced grammar text book and the author and I cannot decide on whether "reign" is an uncountable noun or not.

The sentence is:

> With Mr Smith gone, her reign could begin.

Oxford Dictionaries define *[reign](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reign)* as:

> **1.** (noun) The period of rule of a monarch:
>   *“the original chapel was built in the reign of Charles I”*
>
> **1.1** The period during which someone or something is predominant or pre-eminent:
>   *“she was hoping for a long reign as world champion.”*

The author has identified other words in the passage as uncountable, e.g. *meditation*, *activity*, *emptiness*, *slate*, *glass*, *silence*, but not *reign*.

Comment: What kind of research have you done to try to answer this yourself?

Comment: I checked two grammar guides (including the one I'm working on), a dictionary, I asked our grammar consultant and, as the question states, I discussed it with the author of the grammar book. Then I Googled. Finally I came here, curiousdannii.

Comment: You might feel it wise to look up articles addressing 'countification' and 'massification' here on ELU before you continue. There are grey areas too: see [A blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight).

Comment: Usually it's good practice to explain the reason behind the confusion, that way users understand that you have done some research and they can see where your dilemma lies. A citation that defines *reign* as being countable and one as uncountable, is also helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

"Reign" is an interval of time.  There's no reason that you can't consider several of these.  Consider the book *The History of Scotland During the **Reigns** of Queen Mary and of King James VI* by Robertson and Stewart.  You may also discuss *a* reign of terror in Cambodia under Pol Pot or *the* Reign of Terror in revolutionary France.

All of your examples of noncountable nouns have countable uses, as can be seen by their plural usages and usages with determinatives.

Richard Challoner wrote the book ***Meditations*** or considerations upon Christian truths and duties.

Dennison and Knight: ***Activities*** for Children in Therapy.

From [*Ocean of Nectar: Wisdom and Compassion in Mahayana Buddhism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HlGp6xEbNQUC&pg=PA353&dq=%22emptinesses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMI5cuE58q0xwIVxDQ-Ch3-jwju#v=onepage&q=%22emptinesses%22&f=false)
 By Geshe Kelsang Gyatso

> The four **emptinesses** are: (1) The emptiness of things (2) The
>   emptiness of non-things (3) The emptiness of nature (4) The emptiness
>   of other entities

In 1964, there were two competing **slates** of delegates from Mississippi at the Democratic National Convention.  The challenging slate of the MDFP failed to unseat *the* **slate** of the regular party.

Elizabeth Latham:  ***Silences*** of the Heart

Go [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAEahUKEwj1x7qSzLTHAhWGOz4KHYF8BXY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS0022309303002941&ei=YyzUVbWKFIb3-AGB-ZWwBw&usg=AFQjCNEPkwUaPhtIp2hNb3FEXE6JBdglPA&sig2=Jm1T_WShrKZbcgzcf8oxOQ&bvm=bv.99804247,d.cWw) to read about devitrification of natural rhyolitic obsidian **glasses** ...

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that none of these are uncountable nouns?  You say reign has a countable use, but so do all my other examples. Slate does not appear in the context you assume, but the slate of a roof. I would also say that "emptinesses" and "silences" are used poetically, no?

Comment: @Ferntree Any mass noun can be instantiated: a particular example of *activity* is *an activity;* a particular example of *meditation* is *a meditation* and so on. These particular examples are all countable. That even applies to something like *rice:* you can have several different rices. However I can't see how *reign* can ever be uncountable. You can't have "too much reign".

Comment: @AndrewLeach thanks - that's a great way of formulating it.

Answer (score 1):

So that we can leave poetic usage aside, let's look for some common sense tests:

1. Andrew proposed "**too much** ______ "
2. I like to ask a student if the thing is **like water**.  This seems
   to enable them to figure it out quite quickly.
3. **How much** vs. **how many**?
4. Can I make a sentence with "one ______"?  With "two ______"?

Tests 3 and 4, applied to *activity,* show that *activity* works both ways:

> How much activity does your child need during the day to get a good night's sleep?
>
> How many different activities have you planned for the birthday party?

*Slate* and *glass* can easily work as both types too.  In elementary school, a small blackboard or whiteboard is sometimes called a slate (countable).  The type of rock, on the other hand, is uncountable.  *Glass* is both a material (uncountable) and a cup, only taller, made of glass or another material.

If you disagree with your co-author's pronouncement that a certain word is not countable, just send her a sentence showing that it is.  If she claims something is countable, but you disagree, ask *her* to send *you* a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I think reign is a countable noun because when we say "During his reign ..." it means that his reign was not infinite thus it can be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the nouns referred to can be conceptualised, they elude our sensory organs but that doesn't preclude them to be countable. In other words abstract nouns can be countable. REIGN is a countable noun.

It could have been better if you had left ABSTRACT NOUNS out of your category of countable/uncountable, just limiting yourself to words as simple as 'iron, water, air' etc. For the sake of clarity only.

NOUN>Proper +Common

COMMON NOUNS> Countable + Uncountable
( leaving class/ material/abstract to readers' discretion)

Comment: Many thanks for this. It is an advanced grammar guide so we would not be able to leave abstract concepts off the list, even for the sake of clarity.