# Using 'a' before ''sound sleep''

Tags: indefinite-articles

Should I need to use an 'a' before 'sound sleep' in this sentence ?

''He was in sound sleep''

Regards

Answer (score 1):

[These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+in+sound+sleep%2Cwas+in+a+sound+sleep%2Cwas+soundly+asleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20in%20sound%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20in%20a%20sound%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20soundly%20asleep%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that 'was in sound sleep' *is* used, though not as often as 'in a sound sleep' (though there may be various false positives). But 'was soundly asleep' seems the most idiomatic variant, which is as I imagined.

There are various non-count (* *He was in two sound sleeps that weekend*) expressions favouring/requiring the inclusion of the indefinite article.

*He was in a daze / a coma; this puts it in a different light; she has a working knowledge of Urdu....*

Sometimes, inclusion is optional.

*The director spoke at the meeting today with [a] great enthusiasm.*

The use of the indefinite article with non-count-noun usages has been addressed on ELU at [A blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight).

Answer (score 0):

**sound** used here is an adjective that refers to **deep and undisturbed**. You should use ***a*** before ***sound sleep*** to make it more meaningful.

Here is an example from Oxford dictionary, `His eyes closed gently, as if he was in a sound sleep, his long eyelashes clinging to one another.`[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sound#sound_Adjective_200)

Comment: "Sleep" certainly exists as a countable noun, and can thus take an article. However, the more idiomatic way of putting this would be to say "He was soundly asleep".

Comment: @WS2 Or even just [*he was sound asleep*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sound+asleep).

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, I agree.