# -ness words as count nouns?

Tags: grammaticality, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, nominalizations

I came across this sentence in a book:

> He was astonishingly humble, exhibited great charitableness and such a sweetness and meekness that he would often shed tears at a sad story.

It seems strange to me that the author treats **charitableness** as a mass noun, while **sweetness** is preceded with an indefinite article. Is this construction lawful/grammatical? What is this grammatical phenomenon called?

Comment: Related: [A blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/227855/142322)

Comment: That's purely a question of choice and style. How d'you think the meaning would change if the original had been "such sweetness" without the "a", please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight)

Answer (score 1):

Every word ending with -ness is a noun and can be used as such

> 1. a native English suffix attached to adjectives and participles, forming abstract nouns denoting quality and state (and often, by extension, something exemplifying a quality or state): [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ness)

Comment: The question is about using 'a' with apparent non-count nouns, not fundamentally about nouns ending in -ness.