# Questions about indefinite articles before uncountable nouns

Tags: grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns

I know that you're not usually supposed to use articles before uncountable nouns but that there are sometimes exceptions to this rule. I'm a bit stumped by when the exception applies and when it doesn't. So I was wondering if someone could tell me which is correct in these two situations:

1. Revenge, for example:

> "Is this really (a) revenge orchestrated by those people?"

2. Income, for example:

> "So, if we get (a) stable income and our organization grows larger..."

Comment: They are both being used as count nouns.

Comment: @user No they're not. The only reasonable definition of a count noun usage avoids whether or not a definite article may be used. You can't have 'Are these really a couple of revenges orchestrated by those people?' They are, however, probably best considered as partial countifications.

Comment: Answered for general examples at [A blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight)

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with articles if they're plural articles. "the water" is fine, as is "some water".