# Use of article 'a'

Tags: articles

"to find a moment shrouded in a naked silence"

Is it okay to write 'a' naked silence in place of naked silence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight) (the use of the indefinite article with what many would consider a non-count usage. 2 / some / several / many naked silences?)

Comment: "To dance the line between what is and what is beyond; to find a moment shrouded in a naked silence; and to remember a long-forgotten dream as it becomes a shadow. 
Is it not what beckons a cosmic soul?"

Comment: It's fine by me. And seeing how it's a quote by an artist, it doesn't even matter if it's fine by me or not. It's their poetic license, not mine.

Comment: But the original quoted version ***does*** use *a*. Are you asking, instead, if you can *remove* the article?

Comment: Ya, can it be removed? Or it's just fine...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.

We need more context to give you a better answer.

For example, you could say "there was nothing left but naked silence". You could also say "All I heard was a naked silence."

So, either could be best depending on context.