# How is 'fixture' a count-noun when 'furniture' is a mass noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

*Fixture* is defined in [the LEXICO Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fixture) as:

> A piece of equipment or furniture which is fixed in position in a building or vehicle.

Here're a couple examples from the dictionary:

> *Cathedral ceilings, antique light **fixtures** and furniture that looked as though it had come straight from the twenties.*
>
> *During assembly, the glass is first positioned in **a fixture** with several sensors around the sunroof.*

So, *fixture* seems to be a count-noun, albeit usually used in the plural.

But as its definition indicates, *fixture* is similar in meaning to such mass nouns as *equipment* and *furniture* in that it encompasses different objects with different shapes and functions that can be subsumed under a single category. And I thought this kind of special meaning was the very reason for treating *equipment* and *furniture* as a mass noun, so I was wondering how *fixture* is treated as not a mass noun but a count noun.

Is there anything with *fixture* that distinguishes it from the *equipment*/ *furniture* types of mass nouns that makes it a count noun?

Comment: It says ***a piece of*** equipment or furniture...

Comment: Because English.

Comment: @Jim I know, but that doesn't answer my question. Also note that that's a very poor way of defining the noun, because _a fixture_, but not _fixture_, is "a piece of equipment or furniture..."

Comment: @listeneva - A fixture is ***a*** thing that hold ***something***. It is inherently singular while furniture and equipment are inherently plural.  A light fixture holds a lightbulb. A work fixture holds a piece of work. I think it is not usually used in the plural any more than apple/apples.  I ate an apple, I bought some apples.  I installed a light fixture, I replaced all my bathroom fixtures.  As far  as definitions go,  when I look up ***tree*** I get:  ***a** woody perennial plant*.  When I look up ***house*** I get: ***a** building for human habitation*.  They all start with ***a***.

Comment: @Jim Just because everybody's doing it doesn't mean they're doing it right.

Comment: And you truly believe that’s the case here?

Comment: @Jim If _tree_ is "a woody perennial plant" does _the tree_ mean "the a woody perennial plant"? That's why https://www.collinsdictionary.com/ defines it as follows: "A tree is a tall plant that has a hard trunk, branches, and leaves," not "Tree is a tall plant that has a hard trunk, branches, and leaves." BTW, the dictionary defines _fixture_ as follows: 1. COUNTABLE NOUN [usually plural] "Fixtures are pieces of furniture or equipment, for example baths and sinks, which are fixed inside a house or other building and which stay there if you move."

Comment: @Jim What I really don't understand about what you said, though, is your statement "_furniture_ and _equipment_ are inherently plural." If they are plural, how come they're not treated as such? You can't say _The furniture are wearing out._ or _The equipment are wearing out._.

Comment: What I meant is when you say “the furniture” you are usually referring collectively to multiple pieces of furniture not just to one piece.

Comment: @Jim I'm afraid you're confusing collective nouns such as _police_ with mass nouns such as _furniture_. _The police_ can refer collectively to a plurality of police officers, but never to one police officer. But _the furniture_ definitely can refer to a single piece of furniture.

Comment: When someone says they're moving *the furniture* in a room, it's not referring to a single piece but to more than one piece even if furniture doesn't end with the plural suffix "s". BUT the bathroom fixture (s) and the bathroom fixtures (p) In English  you shouldn't say "The reception furnitures" that is not how native speakers speak.

Comment: @Mari-LouA When that someone has only one piece of furniture in the room, _the furniture_ refers to one piece. So, it's context dependent, not an inherent thing in the noun itself.

Comment: If there's only a single piece,  it would seem to me, to be more logical to call it by its full name, e.g. armchair, sofa, bed, cupboard etc.

Comment: Though there is thankfully a large overlap, there is not a total match between countness of a noun and etic countability of the referent. 'The seven soldiers were sent home. So were the police. In all, ten were sent home.'

Comment: I'm lost. Is OP saying that "I see one furniture in the room" is correct? Or is he saying that it's wrong and asking for some sort of justification for the fact that we say "One fixture" but we do not say "One furniture"?

Comment: @Chaim The latter is what I'm saying.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You've lost me. Could you please rephrase your comment in a layman's term?

Comment: The 'countness' (/non-countness) of a usage is determined by whether a numeral or equivalent (eg 'a dozen',  'several', but not quantifiers) may be inserted. So with  '(a) The soldiers went to the seaside ==> (b) The twelve soldiers went to the seaside' we have a count usage. And with 'We need a new light for the front room ==> We need 3/several new lights for the front room'. But with 'A blinding light filled the clearing' =/=> Two blinding lights filled the clearing' 
 ...

Comment: and 'She/they smiled at us with an unusual friendliness' =/=> She/they smiled at us with several/3 unusual friendlinesses' we have non-count usages. //// 'The furniture is stacked on that platform' shows a non-count usage of 'furniture', though someone not bothered about the peculiarities of English would possibly count the individual items of furniture.... But usually, count usages correspond to countable items.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth AFAIK, dictionaries categorize "light" in "A blinding light filled the clearing" not as a non-count noun but as a count noun or a singular noun. And I'd think 'a singular noun' is subsumed under a count noun rather than a non-count noun.

Comment: I suspect this is a non-question but it occurs to be that furniture comes from *to furnish*, which implies obtaining / arranging *a number of items* in a room etc, whereas *fixture* comes from *to affix*, which means to take something and attach it in a more or less permanent manner, so that it becomes part of the property - so the verbs from which these nouns derive differ in that one is essentially collective and the other is essentially individual. It's not surprising if that difference finds its way through to the nominalised forms.

Comment: @listeneva But CGEL outranks all dictionaries on points of grammar. And the test it gives for a count usage in a sentence is 'May a numeral or equivalent (we're not talking _quantifier_, like 'some', 'less', 'a lot of' here) be acceptably inserted into this usage?' The possibility of using the indefinite article with a non-count usage has been covered on ELU a long time ago (see my answer at ['a blinding light' 'blinding sunlight' 'a blinding sunlight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight'?)).

Comment: @listeneva And it's always best to check. [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light) gives the example 'a bright light' as being an example of a non-count ([U]) usage.

Answer (score 4):

On pages 214-5 of the Google book "[The Oxford Reference Guide to English Morphology](https://books.google.com/books?id=WV9gDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=fixture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&source=bl&ots=FSR9iuoOj0&sig=ACfU3U3iWoEReAKx9mRo7x4v0pCHilgrZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk-uPSnYbnAhVCZM0KHfTaABgQ6AEwDHoECGcQAQ#v=onepage&q=fixture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&f=false)" the authors Laurie Bauer, Rochelle Lieber, and Ingo Plag classify "**fixture**" to be a word:

> "with [lexicalized](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lexicalize) meanings (that) are likelier than non-lexicalized forms to have only the count reading."

[Lexicalization or lexicalisation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lexicalize) is defined in linguistics and British English (since this is coming from the Oxford Dictionary) as

> to form (a word or lexeme) or (of a word or lexeme) to be formed from constituent morphemes, words, or lexemes, as to form cannot from can and not

In the context of "Count vs mass interpretation", a generalization is made between words that have been thoroughly lexicalized as more commonly used as **COUNT** nouns. In contrast, those that have NOT been [lexicalized](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lexicalize) (or have less lexicalization) are more commonly used as **NON-COUNT** nouns.

Here is an image of what I found in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=WV9gDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=fixture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&source=bl&ots=FSR9iuoOj0&sig=ACfU3U3iWoEReAKx9mRo7x4v0pCHilgrZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk-uPSnYbnAhVCZM0KHfTaABgQ6AEwDHoECGcQAQ#v=onepage&q=fixture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&f=false)

[image: ![The Oxford Reference Guide to English Morphology]

Furniture in contrast in the [same book](https://books.google.com/books?id=WV9gDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=fixture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&source=bl&ots=FSR9iuoOj0&sig=ACfU3U3iWoEReAKx9mRo7x4v0pCHilgrZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk-uPSnYbnAhVCZM0KHfTaABgQ6AEwDHoECGcQAQ#v=onepage&q=furniture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&f=false) is described as a non-count because it is a substance

> "treated as undifferentiated (milk, oxygen), abstractions (truth), or aggregates of items, either uniform (rice) or variable (furniture) whose boundaries are not conceptually salient."

Here is an image from pages 124-5 of the [same text in Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=WV9gDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=fixture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&source=bl&ots=FSR9iuoOj0&sig=ACfU3U3iWoEReAKx9mRo7x4v0pCHilgrZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk-uPSnYbnAhVCZM0KHfTaABgQ6AEwDHoECGcQAQ#v=onepage&q=furniture%20count%20vs%20non-count%20-plumbing&f=false):

[image: The Oxford Reference Guide to English Morphology]

Comment: This gives the well-supported answer “because fixture has been lexicalized” but that immediately begs the question “why has it been lexicalized?”. I suspect all roads lead to the flippant answer given by @Hot Licks - “Because English”!

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Before you go down that road, I don't understand what the book means by "lexicalization". The book seems to be saying that _furniture_ is less (or un-)lexicalized. Does that mean that _furniture_ is not an English word or less of an English word than _fixture_? Maybe Karlomanio could elaborate on this matter.

Comment: FYI, this is what I've found about 'lexicalization': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicalization

Comment: @listeneva I defined a lexeme as per British English and Linguistics, which I believe it is referring to.  Hope that helps.  It may muddy the water some, but basically fix- is one lexeme and -ture is another.

Comment: No; you're confusing _lexeme_ with _morpheme_.  // To get rid of extensive yellow highlighting in a highish-end image manipulator, I convert to greyscale, then use 'adjust brightness/contrast/ intensity' to optimise clarity, then see if 'directional sharpen' gets us back to near-original.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Lexicalization can be the process of "form(ing) from constituent ....morphemes, words, or lexemes, as to form cannot from can and not." As I stated above. In this case, the morphemes being "fix-" and "-ture"

Comment: No. You said "... basically 'fix-' is one lexeme and '-ture' is another" in your comment. This time, I've taken a screen-shot.

Comment: I said combining those two are a form of lexicalization.  I did not say whether "fix-" and "-ture" were morphemes or lexemes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure it is important as to who did what or who is "right" and who is "wrong" as to whether we come to a common understanding.

Comment: It's generally considered helpful on ELU not to submit errors.

Comment: @Karlomanio So you're saying that _fixture_ is formed from _fix-_ and _-ture_. Now, can you not argue that _furniture_ is formed from _furni-_ and _-ture_?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that *lexicalize* were chiefly Brittish English. It is not exclusively Brittish. It's just technical jargon.

Comment: @listeneva You raise a good point, but I think the argument here might be that furni- is not a (perfect) morpheme for the object it is representing- i.e. Furnishing being more of a form to meet this rule- i.e. furnishings.  I added a part that explains how furniture is considered non-count.

Comment: @vectory Sorry for the confusion.  That's not what I meant, but  I can see how it left that impression though.  I was quoting the source for the dictionary I was using for the word lexicalize.  The dictionary.com entry shows this as being "BRITISH DICTIONARY DEFINITIONS FOR LEXICALIZE." I believe it is also a general linguistics term and I delineate it separately from the British English term.  The dictionary entry states that it is a "linguistics" term.

Comment: @listeneva One more point.  These are all generalizations.  Not anything specifically right or wrong.  The Oxford dictionary uses terms as "somewhat likelier" indicating that even though you may have a thoroughly lexicalized word, it may not follow the rule they just described.  There are always exceptions in every language that don't follow the generalizations (i.e. "because English").  This book and this answer only provides a framework, not a black and white yes-no answer.  That is what I interpreted the questioner to want.

Answer (score -2):

Probably influenced by *Fixstar* "fixed star" (cp Ger *Fixstern*; En *fixpoint* vs *floating point*). A single fixed star is of course useless. The mythological importance of this should not be understated, if *ster- (cp e.g. Ger *starr* "rigid") pretty much means *fixed* for a couple milenia now, though it can't be conclusively linked to *Hestr- "star".

Other than that, French shows a lot of plural usage for *furnitures* as well as denoting deverbal abstracta, which might be confusing if they elide the plural inflection regularly, as much as article inflection in colloquial speach (*l'furtniture[s]*), though I I'm not sure that was the case when English borrowed it from Middle French.

Comment: I'd suggest you proof-read your post.

Comment: Aye, it's terrible, and typing on mobile is only a weak excuse. But that's the least problem with this post.

Comment: Who said those were the same suffixes? I didn't. Frankly, I don't even care. Given the observation that the countability of a word can change over time, why would the original/historical form of a suffix even matter in answering the question?

Comment: Oh, OK, had to change my answer because I hadn't properly read the question before