# plural subject with uncountable noun "impetus"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

"Free education and health care are among the other impetus". 
Here the subject is plural, and I want to use it with impetus. However, impetus is uncountable. What is the correct form of that sentence?

Comment: Surely, those two things do not in themselves constitute impetus. *Free education and health care are among the benefits.*

Comment: 'Among' cannot normally be used with a non-count usage. Among the hills / trees / daisies / dark old houses / cushions / possibilities / other considerations / .... BUT *Among the countryside / fog / milk / atmosphere / brilliance. Have you checked to see whether 'impetus' has a count usage? Wiktionary is usually braver than other dictionaries in showing countifications.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I tend to agree, believing that it must be a count noun. This is supported by the fact that the OED carries several examples of its use with the indefinite article e.g. *1872   J. Yeats Growth Commerce 238   Fugitive Huguenots gave a fresh impetus to weaving.* A non-count noun cannot take the indefinite, can it? *Air, countryside* and *brilliance* certainly can't, though *fog, milk* and *atmosphere* probably can. But unhelpfully, although the OED lists several different senses of *impetus*, it does not tell you what the plural is - and I have no idea.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The French is *impulsion (f)* but my Oxford Hachette also supplies no suggested plural. Though it would, in the French case, be easier to devise one - presumably *impulsions*.

Comment: Recast. They encouraged; or they also provided impetus for . . .

Comment: @WS2 (0) Although some nouns are perhaps never non-count, perhaps partially justifying the term 'count noun', as most nouns are used in both count and non-count usages at times, it's best to label **usages** (actual appearances in grammatical sentences) count or non-count. // (1) The best diagnostic for a count/non-count usage, according to CGEL and other authorities, is not 'does/can this usage take an indefinite article' but 'does/can this usage take a numeral [the test requires 'numeral', not 'quantifier']. Thus 'They had instilled in him a respect for his traditional culture.' The ...

Comment: notion of numeral-or-equivalent insertion ('They had instilled in him 1 / 5 / a dozen /  ... respect/s for  ...') is ridiculous, of course, so most grammarians would class this as a non-count usage. This example from [Macmillan Dictionary – blog](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/qa-can-the-indefinite-article-be-used-with-uncountable-nouns), but there is further analysis (and there are further examples) at ['A blinding light' / 'blinding sunlight' //// 'a blinding sunlight'??](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight).

Comment: ... On reading the Macmillan article more thoroughly, I see they fall into the "must perpetuate the term 'non-countable noun' (etc) " pitfall. A pity. We usually talk about transitive etc _usages_ for verbs in these enlightened days, to show a fair parallel.

Comment: *A respect/blinding light, above all others he had known.* I guess ultimately all nouns become countable. But I take your point about numeral qualifiers.

Comment: According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/impetus), **impetus** _has_ a count usage with plural form **impetuses**, so 'among the impetuses' _is_ licensed. But then 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' is totally grammatical too. Go with @Xanne's suggestions.

Comment: How about "imputi"?

Comment: Or: "The rarely needed plural is *impetuses*, not *impeti*."  [OxfordReference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199661350.001.0001/acref-9780199661350-e-2776)

Answer (score 4):

*Impetus* is countable. You can say "an impetus for ..." and have it sound perfectly reasonable. You can't do that for uncountable nouns, like "I'm looking for a furniture for my room" or "I just learned an interesting information."

There is a reason that you don't often see the plural. The Latin plural of *impetus* is *impetus*, like all fourth-declension Latin nouns ending with *-us*. This plural was used in English back when most educated English speakers knew Latin. We no longer use this plural (it was always quite rare), but we haven't replaced it with the regular *impetuses*, and *impeti* is just really, truly wrong. This means that *impetus* is in practice a *singulare tantum* — a singular noun that doesn't have any plural.

So what should you do? You could replace it with a synonym (maybe *motivation*). Or you could rephrase the sentence to use *impetus* in the  singular, sort of like an uncountable noun:

> Free education and healthcare are part of the impetus,
> Free education and healthcare contribute to the impetus,

Or you could use *impetuses* as the plural, which seems to be licensed by at least two dictionaries: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/impetuses) and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/impetus).

Comment: Not a good test for countness. 'He took a pride in his appearance' is not seen as a count usage (*'He/They took 2/17/several/half a dozen prides in ...'). // Also, _furnitures_ (eg Louis XIII, Louis XIV) is in use in the trade and by diffusion ....

Comment: @Edwin: so what is a test to distinguish between an uncountable noun and a *singulare tantum*? *Pride* certainly behaves very differently from *impetus* with respect to uncountability. See my next comment:

Comment: [Ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+an+impetus%2Cwas+some+impetus%2Cwas+impetus&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20an%20impetus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20some%20impetus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20impetus%3B%2Cc0) and [Ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+a+pride%2C+took+some+pride%2C+took+pride&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20a%20pride%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20some%20pride%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20pride%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I'm with CGEL here (poor them) in that numeral-insertion is the only test (and corresponding to the only useful definition of countability). _A  blinding light filled the/every clearing._ Non-count usage. // From [telescoper](https://telescoper.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/pluralia-tantum/#:~:text=Indeed%2C%20many%20non%2Dcount%20nouns,does%20take%20on%20that%20role%3F): << Indeed, many non-count nouns exist only in the singular: such nouns are called singularia tantum. Examples include “dust” and “wealth”.>> //// Examples of 'two impetuses' _do_ occur.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It seems that definitions vary. The Purdue OWL website (not untrustworthy for most grammatical matters) [says that](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/count_and_noncount_nouns/count_noncount_nouns_with_articles_adjectives.html) "uncountable nouns never take the indefinite article (a or an), but they do take singular verbs."

Comment: I'm not absolutely always with CGEL, but don't differ here: 'In general, _a_ selects a count singular noun (a cup; *a [health] [but note that countification goes on apace]) ... Under restricted conditions, however, _a_ can combine with a non-count singular (a number of problems remain/He wastes a great deal of time/I have a high regard for them/Jill has a good knowledge of Greek).'

Answer (score 0):

Remember that with the uncountable nouns it is a matter of using a quantifier: *some, several, all*; or a measure word: *piece, bit, slice, bucket, dash, spoon, pound, etc.*

Here maybe **instances of the impetus** will work?

Comment: Thanks, Can I say "Free education and health care are among the several impetus"?

Comment: "Several" is only used for countable nouns. Consider rephrasing the sentence

Comment: I can only guess that maybe you want to make it more compact but here it will bring more vagueness than clarity.
_Free education and health care are among the other cases of the impetus_ — is this better?

Answer (score 0):

"Impetus" is usually used in the following structure

- ___ gave Impetus to ____
- ____ received Impetus from _____

So there aren't many ordinary cases where the plural "impetuses" is required

For example, "Free education and healthcare gave great impetus to the development of the nation"

Even "Free education and healthcare also gave new impetus" is correct provided context is supplied elsewhere

The way you've used it is rather clunky.