# Free hand: uncountable

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, dictionaries

> **Free hand** [countable; singular]
>
> ​ Unrestricted freedom or
> authority: *They gave the director a free hand to cut the budget
> wherever she wanted​*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/free%20hand

However, the Random House Learner's Dictionary explains the *NOUN GRAMMAR CODES* as follows

> **[count]** it can be counted and has a plural. It can be used with the word *a* or *an* before it.
>
> **[singular]** only used in the singular with a singular verb. It can be
> used with *a* or *an* before it.

Therefore, isn't adding both codes in the same word contradictory?

Comment: 'Give someone a free hand' undergoes limited variation, surely, so that 'She gave them a free hand' (not 'She gave them free hands') is idiomatic. I'd say 'hand' is outside the count/noncount classification here, and certainly not count. // Google results ... "them free hands" _has_ tokens, but is outperformed by "them a free hand" by over 100:1. // Even if the plural-form variant is considered acceptable, as 'She gave them 2/6/17 free hands' is certainly **not** acceptable, the usage is (see CGEL) non-count.

Comment: Word Reference is not the Random House Dictionary. They appear use the codes slightly differently.

Comment: @PeterShor I checked the paper dictionary too

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The entry of **hand** shows either of two grammar codes for its several meanings: _[countable]_ and _[singular]_ https://www.wordreference.com/definition/hand

Comment: For the plural: *I used my **two free hands**.*

Comment: The committee gave both the applicants a free hand regarding their presentations.

Comment: @JasonBassford **FREE**: 8b. phr. _(to have or give) a free hand_: liberty of action in affairs that one has to deal with. So _to have one's hands free_ https://oed.com/oed2/00089640

Answer (score 1):

**Free hand** is "countable" and "singular".  So is "potato".  If there is more than one potato in the bag you have a bag of "potatoes".

If I gave a "free hand" to both Fred and Jack to pursue their respective duties, I could say I gave both Fred and Jack "free hands".

There is nothing remarkable about this.

Comment: I'd disagree about 'free hand' being count. As I've said above, the plural form can be found ('they were given free hands to ...') but no one would say 'clothes' is count in 'they were given clothes'. 'They were given 7 clothes'? '7 free hands'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Uh, how would you know if "clothes" were singular or plural?  Closeses?  Closei?  There is a very practical reason why "clothes" is uncountable.  There is no practical issue with making "free hand" countable.

Answer (score 0):

Uncountable nouns (or, more precisely, nouns used in uncountable senses) do not take an indefinite article.  The fact that one can say "a free hand" means that the noun phrase "free hand" is countable, by definition.

The [singular] code, by contrast, means that this sense is only ever used in the singular.

The two codes therefore do not contradict each other.

Comment: This has been shown not to be the whole picture here on ELU before. 'He really took a pride in his performance.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I look forward to an answer providing more depth.  Or a link to a relevant question or answer.

Comment: I can link to an earlier question dealing with the 'do non-count usages sometimes take a definite article' issue, but not to one looking at 'gave them a free hand / ??gave them free hands // *gave them two free hands' example. But there are many invariant-for-singular-form idioms where examining for countness is counterproductive. [a blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight). Note that your answer does not provide _specific_ support (and is, I have to say, inaccurate).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks, I missed that one.

Comment: The CGEL test for countness in a usage is 'Can a numeral (or 'a dozen' etc) (but not any old quantifier) be inserted in situ?' 'A blinding light flooded the room' / *'Two blinding lights flooded the room'. 'He took two prides in his appearance' is incontestably unacceptable (except in spoof).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _any old quantifier_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Contrary to the tendency shown in NGrams, OED reads:  **PRIDE** 4. A feeling of elation, pleasure, or high satisfaction derived from some action or possession; _esp. in to **take a pride (in,** †to do something, etc.)._
https://oed.com/oed2/00188461

Comment: @GJC 'Took some / a lot of / ...', as well as the article example 'took a pride in ...' _are_ acceptable. The test is with 5 / 23756 / a dozen ....

Answer (score 0):

It’s an idiom.

> a free hand

> Complete freedom to do what one wants or chooses.
> Can you believe the boss gave me a free hand on this project? Finally, I can present a campaign with my own vision!

Comment: Cambridge reads _**free hand** [ S  ]_ but  _**free rein**
noun [ U ]_. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/help/codes.html

Answer (score 0):

The countability is a red-herring.

The OED classes a free hand as a phrase:

> P5. ***to have a free hand* (also to have one's hands free): to have the freedom to act completely at one's own discretion. Also *with a free hand, with one's hands free*; similarly *to give a free hand.***
>
> 1838   Times 5 Jan. 6/2   *If..Lord Mulgrave had been sent out to Canada with his hands free, and with unfettered power to carry into effect his own wise and benevolent views.*
>
> [...]
>
> 1989   AJ 28 June 15/3   *The council..had wisely given the community group a fairly free hand in converting the building.*
>
> 2002   Independent 9 Apr. 8/2   *The photographer..was recruited by Luciano Benetton..in 1983 with a free hand to sell the brand.*

As such, it is set and not really capable of being analysed any more than "He gave me carte blanche."

To add to this, it is probably an idiom - there is not much sense in the literal version - what can you do when one hand is not "free"? It is hardly the complete freedom that the phrase/idiom implies.