# "is lack" or "is a lack"?

Tags: grammaticality

Are there any differences between the uses/meanings of "is lack" and "is a lack" for example in the following?

> There is a lack of interest in the topic.
> There is lack of research on the subject.

Comment: [Does this help answer your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lack-of-confidence-and-lack-of-confidence/564887#564887)?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, despite "lack" being a word that sometimes does and sometimes does not get an article, "there is lack" of something sounds completely wrong to me, coming from the U.S.  I think you need an "a" here in all cases.

Comment: the andy bonner link does answer my question

Comment: I'd not call this a count usage. *'There are 3 lacks of interest in the class.' However, as has been discussed earlier, the use of the indefinite article is not confined to count usages. 'He took a pride in his appearance' / 'She received a fine education in the sciences' / 'A dappled light illuminated the clearing.' ////  'A lack of' is a fixed phrase, so as @cruthers says, dropping the article sounds off.